# How do I create a table constraint to prevent duplicate values across two columns?

Tags: sql, constraints, alter-table

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EntityAttributeRelship](
    [IdNmb] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EntityIdNmb] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AttributeIdNmb] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_EntityAttributeRelship_IsActive]  DEFAULT ((0)),
CONSTRAINT [PK_EntityAttributeRelship] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
([IdNmb] ASC) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY]
```

A portion of the data in the table looks like something this:

```
IdNmb    EntityIdNmb    AttributeIdNmb  IsActive
1        22             7               0
2        22             8               0
3        22             9               0
4        22             10              1
```

I want to add a constraint to make sure that no one adds or updates a record to have IsActive = 1, if there is already a record for the EntityIdNmb where IsActive = 1.

How do I do this?

Comment: @Eric, if time permits, would you care to explain why the Clustered Indexed View solution tomfut and I presented does not satisfy your request? I consider CI Views to be an elegant solution to this kind of problems.

Comment: @Lieven and @tomfut, I created a trigger to do this, but I will try your solution as well, since I misunderstood your answer at first. thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using SQLServer you can create a clustered indexed view.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.VIEW_EntityAttributeRelship WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
SELECT EntityIdNmb 
FROM dbo.EntityAttributeRelship
WHERE IsActive = 1
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX UIX_VIEW_ENTITYATTRIBUTERELSHIP 
  ON dbo.VIEW_EntityAttributeRelship (EntityIdNmb)
```

This ensures there's only one EntityIdNmb in your table with IsActive = 1.

Comment: This won't work. I need to return all records, not just records where IsActive = 1.

Comment: @Eric, did you really downvoted me for this without even trying it? It does what you ask "no one adds or updates a record to have IsActive = 1, if there is already a record for the EntityIdNmb where IsActive = 1".

Comment: i apologize. i have removed the downvote. i misunderstood your answer. i thought you were telling me to use a view to retrieve my data from.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you need to implement a trigger (assuming your db product supports it). If you only want one active and one inactive entry, a unique index will work. Otherwise, you'll need to write some sort of custom constraint or a trigger (probably 2 - one for inserts, one for updates) that makes sure that you don't have 2 records with the same id where both are active.

Comment: could you provide more insight into what to write in my trigger? do i perform a rollback or what?

Comment: Eric, if you find that there's a conflict, throw an exception. A trigger isn't much different than a stored proc - you just register it differently so the db knows when to execute it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using MSSQL (I think that's what your syntax looks like), Create a view including only the rows with IsActive = 1, then put a unique index on EntityIdNmb in the view.

In PostgreSQL, which I've worked more with recently, you can create a partial index:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/indexes-partial.html

Comment: @tomfut, you seem to be having the same idea as I had. For one reason or another, it does not satisfy the request of the OP.

Comment: @Lieven, and your answer was first and more detailed!  Sorry for the spam.

Belair seems to take your answer to imply that he should then do his SELECTS from the view, not the original table.

Comment: @tomfut, no harm done. Perhaps you are right in your assumption about selecting from the view. @Belair, if you should read this, that assumption is not true. Just select, update and insert into your original table. The CI View will take care of the constraint.

Answer (score 1):

The thing with writing the trigger is to decide whether you want to reject the record, change the value to 0 instead of one or update the old record to zero and let this one stand as one.  If you are deleting the record with the value of 1, do you need to change another record to be the active one, how to do you choose which one? Once you can define waht you want to do within the trigger, we can help you better to design the process.

We do the latter two steps to make any address the main mailing address in our database.  Our business rule is one and only one address can be the main one and if there are any addresses one must be marked as the main one. The key to this sort of trigger is to remember that inserts/updates/deletes can occur in batches (even if this is the not the norm) and to make sure the trigger works in a set-based fashion. When I got here, ours implemented multi-row processing through a cursor which became a bad thing when I had to update 200,000 addresss in an import. (Note to the inexperienced - do not ever use a cursor in a trigger!)

Answer (score 0):

What will the inactive records be used for?  Are they unused and simply there to keep track of previously active records?  If so, would it be possible to split the data in to multiple tables?  Something like...

EntityAttributeRelship(IDNmb, EntityIDNmb, AttributeIDNmb)

EntityAttributeRelshipHistory(IDNmb, EntityIDNmb, AttributeIDNmb)

If it's in the EntityAttributeRelship table, it's active.  If it's in the history table then it was activated at some point and has since been deactivated?

If you do need everything in one table I would go with todd.run's suggestion of using a trigger.

Comment: I do need everything in one table. It is an existing table and the data is already there. I just need to add a constraint. If I need a trigger, that's understandable, I just need to know what to write.